# A "Journal of Irreproducible Results" entry asserting that any obtuse angle is right.

Tags: geometry, reference-request, math-history

According to the [*Journal of Irreproducible Results*](http://www.jir.com), any obtuse angle is a right angle! (See below.)

My questions are:

> 1. What is the publication date, and number of the issue of the problem?
> 2. Who proved the wrong statements?

Here is their argument, as quoted elsewhere on the web. (Note that I am not asking to resolve the geometric fallacy.)

> Given the obtuse angle $x$, we make a quadrilateral $ABCD$ with $\angle DAB = x$, $\angle ABC = 90^\circ$, and $\overline{AD} \cong \overline{BC}$. Say the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{DC}$ meets the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$ at $P$. Then $\overline{PA} \cong \overline{PB}$ and $\overline{PC} \cong \overline{PD}$. So the $\triangle PAD$ and $\triangle PBC$ have equal sides and are congruent. Thus $\angle PAD \cong \angle PBC$. But $\triangle PAB$ is isosceles, hence $\angle PAB \cong \angle PBA$. Subtracting gives $$x = \angle PAD − \angle PAB = \angle PBC − \angle PBA = 90^\circ$$ 
>   This is a preposterous conclusion. Just where is the mistake in the "proof" , and why does the argument break down there?

Comment: Please answer the questions , not the geometry

Comment: Please, a request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Martin Gardner's [The Universe in a Handkerchief](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387946733) credits [The Lewis Carroll picture book](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/the-lewis-carroll-picture-book-selection-from-the-unpublished-writings-and-drawings-of-lewis-carroll-together-with-reprints-from-scarce-and-unacknowledged-work_lewis-carroll/17514997/#isbn=1506198007&idiq=22674377) for this fallacious proof.

Comment: The journal has been called "the Mad Magazine of science".... Euclid's writings include some geometric paradoxes similar to this one, as challenges  for students.